# How to add protocol to url like '//abc.com' in electron?

Tags: protocols, electron

Now with the url like '//abc.com', electron will automatically redirect to 'file://abc.com'. Is there a way to add `https` protocol head to that url instead of `file`?

Answer (score 0):

```
const shell = require('electron').shell;

webContents.on('new-window', function(event, url){
  event.preventDefault();
  if (url.startsWith('//')) {
    url = 'https:' + url;
  }
  shell.openExternal(url)
});
```

Comment: thanks for the comment! my scenario is a bit different, I have some resources that will be requested after the window is created, how to force all the external resources either load sync or async to go through `https`?